# How to download single page in separate folders with wget

Tags: javascript, html, web-crawler, wget

I want to download a single page of a website.

I can use Chrome `Save as` but all assets will be saved in one directory (website_files).

I used **Webhttrack** but it's not work on `https`

How can I save files in folders as page structure with `wget`? If you know other tools, please tell me.

Eg: `example.com/js/js.js` should be stored in `js` folder

Comment: start here http://www.veen.com/jeff/archives/000573.html then share your progresses

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. I think I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DaFois, I solved my problem. Here is the command I used:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -N -p -P somename http://example.com/something
```

**Reference:**

https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/03a10e850656577cfb57
http://www.veen.com/jeff/archives/000573.html